# Select box not binding correctly in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS binding doesn't work well with a selectbox. I have the following select:

```
<select id="ratingProject" data-ng-model="rt.project" data-ng-options="prj.name for prj in projectList"></select>
```

And a button that should update its value via a method:

```
<button data-ng-click="rating.modify($index)">Modify</button>
```

The method's code is:

```
$scope.rating = {
        modify : function(index) {
            var newRating = $.extend(true, {}, $scope.subcontractor.ratings[index]);
            $scope.rt = newRating;
            $scope.rt.index = index;
        }
    };
```

But this doesn't work, if I click on the button, the selectbox doesn't update its value. The problem only happens with selectbox, it works if I put a text input as follows :

```
<input type="text" id="ratingProject" data-ng-model="rt.project.name" />
```

The object has the following structure:

```
rating {
    project{
        id,
        name
    },
    stars,
    comments
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: This isn't a problem with the select box, it is a problem with your `modify` function. Don't use `$.extend`, this is jQuery and it is not angular aware.  use `angular.extend` instead.

Comment: Thanks, still doesn't work, I used `angular.extend` but i could also just use `$scope.rt = $scope.subcontractor.ratings[index];` and it still wont work

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your button is trying to do here.  The `data-ng-model=rt.project` assumes that you have multiple `prj` and that the one you select is being set to `rt.project`, but in your `modify` function, you are replacing the *entire* `rt`, which doesn't really make sense.  moreover, the text input that you suggest works isn't changing `rt`, it is changing `rt.project.name`.

Comment: My button is trying to bind data to inputs, the `$scope.rt` object is referenced in `ngModel` of the inputs and by clicking it should fill in in the data, it works for text inputs but not for select. When I replace the whole `$scope.rt` project I'm trying to fill in all the inputs via binding. The structure of `$scope.rt` is the one I described in the end of my post.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense what you are trying to accomplish; can you provide a [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I resolved the problem by adding  `track by prj.id` to `ng-options`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding `track by prj.id` to `ng-options`

Answer (score 0):

Change the parameter your passing to the function

```
<button data-ng-click="rating.modify(prj)">Modify</button>
```